# Equal variables - Batch

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd, findstr

So, I've the following batch script:

```
@echo off
 set /p name= 
 rem a random number, don't care about it.
 set complete_name=%name%.Creepy
 Goto STEP1
:STEP1
 echo %complete_name%|findstr /C:"9000" >nul 2>&1
 if not errorlevel 1 (
 goto 9000
 ) else ( 
 GOTO CHECK2
 )
 :CHECK2
 echo %complete_name%|findstr /C:"930" >nul 2>&1
 if not errorlevel 1 (
 goto 930
 ) else ( 
 GOTO CHECK3
 )
 :CHECK3
 echo %complete_name%|findstr /C:"310" >nul 2>&1
 if not errorlevel 1 (
 goto 310
 ) else ( 
 ECHO PROBLEM
 ) 
 :9000 
 ECHO 9000
 PAUSE
 :930
 ECHO 930
 PAUSE
 :310
 ECHO 310
 PAUSE
```

I want it to check if "9000" is in the variable or not, same for "930" and "310". And if none of these numbers are in the variable Echo problem. But everytime i run this script it goes to `ECHO PROBLEM` even if 9000/920/310 is in `%complete_name%`. So, is this the right way to check if a variable is in another one or there is an easier way to do it?

So I've tried this code:

```
@echo off
set name=310
set complete_name=%name%.Creepy
Goto STEP1
:STEP1
 setlocal
    if "%complete_name:9000=%"=="%complete_name%" (
      if "%complete_name:930=%"=="%complete_name%" (
        if "%complete_name:310=%"=="%complete_name%" (
        echo PROBLEM
        ) else ( 
        goto 9000
        ) 
      ) else ( 
      goto 930
      ) 
    ) else ( 
    goto 310
    )
    goto :eof
```

but I'm stuck at `echo problem`...

Comment: Instead of using `GOTO`s, try nested `IF ... ( ... ) ELSE ( ... )` approach. And learn [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: in matter of fact this works for me .excluding the fact that your subroutines are not ended with `exit /b` or `goto :eof` .

Comment: @JosefZ my goald isn't to "Edit/Replace" a variable. And I didn't understand how can I use `IF ... ( ... ) ELSE ( ... )` instead of `GOTO`.
@npocmaka this is just a part of the script i'm trying to use. So i use "PAUSE" to test if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save next code snippet, possibly named `blabla.bat`:

```
@Echo OFF
setlocal
set complete_name=%1
if "%complete_name:9000=%"=="%complete_name%" ( 
  if "%complete_name:930=%"=="%complete_name%" ( 
    if "%complete_name:310=%"=="%complete_name%" ( 
      echo problem 
    ) else ( 
      echo valid 310
    ) 
  ) else ( 
    echo valid 930
  ) 
) else ( 
  echo valid 9000
)
Exit /B
```

and watch the output from

```
blabla x9000y
blabla x930y
blabla x310y
blabla x9a0b0c0y
```

That's a way of 1. nested `IF ... ( ... ) ELSE ( ... )` and 2. using "Edit/Replace" a variable

Or, if `GOTO`s considered necessary, there is something similar with `For` loop (a good thought topic as well..).

```
@Echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set complete_name=%1
for %%G in (9000 930 310) DO (
  if /I "!complete_name:%%G=!" neq "%complete_name%" GOTO :%%G
)
echo problem %complete_name%
GOTO :commonEnd
:9000
  Echo valid 9000 %complete_name%
  GOTO :commonEnd
:930
  Echo valid 930 %complete_name%
  GOTO :commonEnd
:310
  Echo valid 310 %complete_name%
  GOTO :commonEnd
:commonEnd
```

Comment: There is something wrong in your edit: nesting should follow next pattern (outer items should correspond): `A B C ... C B A`. Your pattern is `A B C ... A B C` ( instantiated: `9000 930 310 ... 9000 930 310` ). Also see my edit, mind all `GOTO :commonEnd` ...